# Move element from child component to its parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to design an ApiFetcher in order to prevent duplicate code.

How to I pass a custom child component to my ApiFetcher so that it renders the content I specify in the custom component instead of a hard coded element in the return statement?

I want to keep the logic of the ApiFetcher and the CompanyProfile components out of their parent components.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function ApiFetcher(props) {
  const apiUrl =
    "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/AAPL?apikey=demo";

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    // TODO: move the following <div> out of this component and render children
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.symbol}>
            {item.companyName} {item.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function CompanyProfile() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ApiFetcher>
        {/*
        TODO: move the following into this component:

      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.symbol}>
            {item.companyName} {item.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    */}
      </ApiFetcher>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CompanyProfile />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: props.children don't work?

Comment: You are right, I should've taken the code one step further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use `props.children` in order to move rendering logic to Parent component. Here's how I will strucutre the component:

```
function ApiFetcher({url}) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return props.children({response: items});
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ApiFetcher>
{({response}) => // Rendering logic}
</ApiFetcher>
```